# openAcc : is there any directive corresponding to THREADPRIVATE in openMP

Tags: openmp, openacc

I am trying to transform an openMp program to openAcc program.i encountered threadprivate directive.i need to know is there any such directive in openAcc
if there is no such directive in openAcc,how to handle such scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that "private" and "threadprivate" differ in that "threadprivate" allows each thread to have a local copy that is persistent to a thread through the execution of multiple parallel regions.

With OpenACC 1.0, there is no way to ensure this yet.

my 2cents...